# freebase search api

Tags: google-api, freebase, mql, google-api-client, mqlwrite

How can I only return results which have a notable type?

IE when I have the default example:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=nirvana&indent=true

It normally returns something like:

```
{
  "mid": "/m/015k7",
  "name": "Gautama Buddha",
  "notable": {
    "name": "Deity",
    "id": "/religion/deity"
  },
  "lang": "en",
  "score": 24.125902
}...
```

which is perfect, but sometimes it doesn't have a notable type and returns only:

```
{
      "mid": "/m/01rkx5",
      "name": "Mahayana Mahaparinirvana Sutra",
      "lang": "en",
      "score": 22.350945
    },
```

How can i filter out all results except those that have a notable type?

I tried setting

```
filter = (all notable) but it expects (all notable:something)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, its not possible to filter search results based on whether notable types exists. I've passed your suggestion on to the Freebase engineers and they'll considering whether to add this in a future release of the Search API.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to hear, but that is a definitive answer. ;-)  Thanks